# why php curl is pointing to php_curl.dll instead curl.so ubuntu

Tags: php, curl, configuration, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run php file using command line php and it is throwing error error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

After this i commented the extention curl in php.ini, but stilll getting the same error.

Comment: It presumably must be mentioned in a config file somewhere, although not necessarily `php.ini` itself. Can you try running `grep -ri curl.dll /etc/php*`? That might give you a pointer.

Comment: nothing found..